# div breaks out of its container

Tags: css, html

I believe there is a simple answer to this question but I have an issue where my content div container doesn't extend far enough for me to scroll through my textbox div.

It seems like there is an additional 200-300 px below the content div that is preventing me from seeing everything in the textbox div, even when there is no scrolling needed I cannot view the page because my background colour is covering the last 200-300 px of text data. I have tried putting an empty div inside the textbox and at the bottom of the content div but no use... Here is my code. If you need more info to help me I can provide it.

Relevant CSS:

```
#imgscroll{
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:998;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 254px;
    top: 0px;
    width: *;
    height:auto;
    min-width:500px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: #FFF;
    z-index:1;
}
#textbox{
    position:relative;
    top:210px;
    background-color:#CFF;
    margin:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:12px;
    min-width:500px;
}
#footer{
    position:relative;
    background-color: #099;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<div id="content">
<div id="imgscroll">

<ul id="scroller">

    <li><img src="images/slider/image-1.JPG" width="267" height="200"></li>

    <li><img src="images/slider/image-2.jpg" width="267" height="200"></li>

    <li><img src="images/slider/image-3.JPG" width="267" height="200"></li>

    <li><img src="images/slider/image-4.JPG" width="267" height="200"></li>

    <li><img src="images/slider/image-5.jpg" width="267" height="200"></li>

    <li><img src="images/slider/image-6.JPG" width="267" height="200"></li>

</ul>

</div>

<div id="textbox">
<h1>Home</h1>
<br />
All my text is here empty divs below don't fix it. Usually this text is much longer and 

whether there is scrolling involved or not, it is still an issue.<br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /> I cannot see this text at the bottom.
<div> </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
(c) My Company Name 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6yKsJ/

Comment: I cannot remove the absolute from imgscroll as it causes undesirable effects when a user decides to resize their browser while on my page. This was code provided with the imgscroller JS code. And if I remove relative from my textbox it will move into the imgscroll.

Comment: OK so first off this community is great! second I've edited my jsfiddle to include the slider code...it is called simplyscroller http://jsfiddle.net/6yKsJ/3/  So I have tried playing with the positioning in dreamweaver but by doing so I create more problems. right now the page functions but when I remove the position from #imgscroll it breaks, when I remove position from #textbox it will move into the imgscroller. Any other possible solutions? Assuming I cannot change the position of the imgscroll.

Comment: I've managed to figure it out thanks to all the help. By moving the imgscroll outside of the content div and removing the positioning tags from the textbox I achieved the result I was looking for. Thanks for all the help, couldn't have done it without help from this community!

Answer (score 0):

Whats with all the positions? thats the cause of the issue -

```
#imgscroll{
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    /*position:absolute;*/
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:998;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/xZXUC/

If you have a reason then I get you but thats the root of all evil.

Comment: it didn't display properly before I added that line. it would break if I resized the browser, the images would stop scrolling and the page would become the total width of my images, not cool.

Comment: I see ...but my point is there is another way then to deal with positionings

Comment: how can I do this? Sorry to sound so noobish but... well I am.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in what context this code is used but you can remove a lot of the `position` definitions:

- Remove `position: absolute;` from `#imgscroll`
- Remove `position:
  relative;` form `#textbox` and `#footer`

And then to display the whole textbox content you should also remove `overflow: hidden` form `#textbox`.

I don't know if it is exactly what you want. Have a look at [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DNTBk/1/).

Comment: got the fiddle to replicate my issue see comment above

Comment: I believe that there will be some sort of javascript slider but I can't figure out the problem without seeing it. What exactly do you mean with "breaks"? Maybe you can add the slider code to the fiddle...

Comment: Added the code in there but I'm not sure how to properly format it in JSfiddle. I've never added JS in there ironically enough.